# Regression Analysis in Expenditure based problems

Tags: regression

I have a doubt regarding prediction of expenditure of a single person's data. For example, if we have data of expenditure of 5 days say 'food', can we predict the the expense of 6th day using regression analysis.  To be more specific, if my expenditure of food are 50, 100, 155, 145 and 100 for day 1, day 2, day 3, day 4 and day 5 respectively.  Can we use linear regression in this case?.  If yes what will be the independent variable.  I have a very little knowledge in statistics, so please help me in this regard

Comment: With no other information a best guess in a least squares sense for day 6 is the mean of expenditures for days 1 to 5, which is in fact a regression result. Any good regression code will return the mean given only a response variable. Otherwise I don't know how seriously your example should be taken, but a statistical person would ask: Is expenditure the cost of food eaten that day, or the amount spent per day? What days of the week are meant? For example, the 6th day might be a non-shopping day. More generally, no good model beyond calculating a mean is possible without more information.

Comment: Thankyou.  By expenditure I meant the cost of food eaten that day. From monday to friday.

Comment: So, you have more information that you gave us. The question could be cultural here as much as statistical. Is Saturday's expenditure expected to differ from the mean of Monday to Friday?

Comment: yeah... anything other than average?

Comment: Look at your question. It is: can we use linear regression and comments explain yes and say more. If it’s now can we do anything else? Then yes again. You could use the median, for example. But the question now lacks even what little focus it had.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on Nick's comments:

Right now, you have two variables: Day and expense. If that's all the data you have then the only possible regression would be to have expense as the dependent variable and day as the independent variable. You *could* do this and you will get an intercept and a coefficient for day. It doesn't violate any rules to do so. The equation you get is:

$Expense = 66.5 + 14.5D$

But then you want to extrapolate to day 6. And it becomes clear that a linear trend by day makes no sense. It would mean that the expense on (say) day 100 would be $66.5 + 145 = 220$.

The best approach, with so little data, is to just use either the mean or the median, depending on exactly what you are trying to predict.

If you gathered data for a lot more days then you could do something sensible, perhaps using day of week as an independent variable or looking for cyclical patterns.